# Group by multiple fields and then generate a sum

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, collections, laravel-5

I have a recipe building application based on Laravel 5.2.

Users can add ingredients to their recipes and occasionally you may add the same ingredient twice depending on what you are using the ingredient for.

I'm building functionality to allow a user to generate a shopping list for their recipe, this should generate a PDF shopping list for them.

So far I have the list of ingredients being generated, but I can't quite wrap my head around how to go about grouping and summing the amounts.

A typical list might look like this:

```
[  
   {  
      "id":97724,
      "name":"Citra Pellets",
      "amount":6.5,
      "hop_type_id":"Pellet",
      "recipe_id":23453
   },
   {  
      "id":97725,
      "name":"Simcoe Pellets",
      "amount":6.5,
      "hop_type_id":"Pellet",
      "recipe_id":23453
   },
   {  
      "id":97726,
      "name":"Citra Pellets",
      "amount":6.5,
      "hop_type_id":"Pellet",
      "recipe_id":23453
   },
   {  
      "id":97727,
      "name":"Simcoe Pellets",
      "amount":6.5,
      "hop_type_id":"Pellet",
      "recipe_id":23453
   },
   {  
      "id":97729,
      "name":"Mosaic Pellets",
      "amount":79.9999,
      "hop_type_id":"Pellet",
      "recipe_id":23453
   },
   {  
      "id":97730,
      "name":"Simcoe Pellets",
      "amount":60,
      "hop_type_id":"Combined",
      "recipe_id":23453
   }
]
```

Currently, I just have a `foreach` loop going over these in my view to spit out the results; which come out something like this:

```
+--------+----------------+------------+
| Amount |      Name      | Usage Type |
+--------+----------------+------------+
|    6.5 | Citra Pellets  | Pellet     |
|    6.5 | Simcoe Pellets | Pellet     |
|    6.5 | Citra Pellets  | Pellet     |
|    6.5 | Simcoe Pellets | Pellet     |
|  79.99 | Mosaic Pellets | Pellet     |
|     60 | Simcoe Pellets | Combined   |
+--------+----------------+------------+
```

What I am wanting to do is group the ingredients by their name and usage type, and then get the sum of the amounts. So output being something like this:

```
+--------+----------------+------------+
| Amount |      Name      | Usage Type |
+--------+----------------+------------+
|     13 | Citra Pellets  | Pellet     |
|     13 | Simcoe Pellets | Pellet     |
|  79.99 | Mosaic Pellets | Pellet     |
|     60 | Simcoe Pellets | Combined   |
+--------+----------------+------------+
```

My attempts so far have included `App\Models\Recipe::find(23453)->hops->groupBy('name')` - this gives me something like the below:

```
{  
   "Citra Pellets":[  
      {  
         "id":97724,
         "name":"Citra Pellets",
         "amount":6.5,
         "hop_type_id":"Pellet",
         "recipe_id":23453
      },
      {  
         "id":97726,
         "name":"Citra Pellets",
         "amount":6.5,
         "hop_type_id":"Pellet",
         "recipe_id":23453
      },
      {  
         "id":97728,
         "name":"Citra Pellets",
         "amount":94.9999,
         "hop_type_id":"Pellet",
         "recipe_id":23453
      }
   ],
   "Simcoe Pellets":[  
      {  
         "id":97725,
         "name":"Simcoe Pellets",
         "amount":6.5,
         "hop_type_id":"Pellet",
         "recipe_id":23453
      },
      {  
         "id":97727,
         "name":"Simcoe Pellets",
         "amount":6.5,
         "hop_type_id":"Pellet",
         "recipe_id":23453
      },
      {  
         "id":97730,
         "name":"Simcoe Pellets",
         "amount":60,
         "hop_type_id":"Combined,
         "recipe_id":23453
      }
   ],
   "Mosaic Pellets":[  
      {  
         "id":97729,
         "name":"Mosaic Pellets",
         "amount":79.9999,
         "hop_type_id":"Pellet",
         "recipe_id":23453
      }
   ]
}
```

This then allows me to loop over each and then `->sum('amount')` to get the sum value. However it doesn't take into account the `hop_type_id` which is important.

I tried chaining `->groupBy('hop_type_id')` on too, and variations of using `->each(function ($item, $key))` but haven't managed to solve this yet.

It looks like the initial `groupBy()` on the collection produces an object of keys that have an array of the values underneath them.

What I am ideally after is another level under each hop name for each of the `hop_type_id`s that I can then use to generate the sum for each hop `name` and `hop_type_id`.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this-

```
\App\Ingredient::where('recipe_id','=',23453)->selectRaw('sum(amount) as amount, name, hop_type_id')->groupBy('name')->groupby('hop_type_id')->get();
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I'll give this a go, but was keen to achieve this with the existing query.

Comment: @James sometimes breakdown part by part is necessary, if it helps then let me know, i will try with your existing query.

Answer (score 0):

You could rewrite the whole recept as an array of ingredients. This way the type of a Recept object would be

```
     Ingredient[]
```

Each ingredient would have the following private fields with corresponding public getters

```
         $id, (string) $name, (int) $amount, $hop_type_id, $recipe_id
```

You could then generate a shopping list like follows

```
$shoppingList = [];
foreach($recept as $ingredient) {
    $shoppingList[$ingredient->getName()] += $ingredient->getAmount();
}
```

Comment: This is a new feature to an existing application, no chance of a rewrite sadly.

Comment: What if in your result with the foreach loop you just check whether an ingredient has ben already added to the list? If yes you just add the new quantity, in the other case you add a new wlement to the list. If you publish your foreach loop I can be more concrete.

Answer (score 0):

So I solved it using the existing collection, without having to use a raw query or modifying the database schema.

You can use `groupBy()` and then `transform()` to achieve this:

```
$recipe = App\Models\Recipe::find(23453);

$hops = $recipe->hops->groupBy('name')
        ->transform(function ($hop, $key) {
            return $hop->groupBy('hop_usage_type');
        });
```